# PHP open gzipped XML

Tags: php, xml, gzip, xmlreader

I am struggling to read gzipped xml files in php.

I did succeed in reading normal xml files, using XMLReader() like this:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($linkToXmlFile);
```

However, this does not work when the xml file is gzipped. How can I unzip the file and read it with the XMLReader?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you didn't specify a PHP version, I am going to assume you are using PHP5.

I am wondering why people haven't suggested using the built in [PHP compression streams API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php).

```
$linkToXmlFile = "compress.zlib:///path/to/xml/file.gz";
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($linkToXmlFile);
```

From what I understand, under the covers, it will transparently decompress the file for you and allow you to read it as if were a plain xml file. Now, that may be a gross understatement.

Comment: it is indeed something like this I'm looking for... I will try it this evening...

Comment: @Fortega, that's what I'm here for.

Comment: Awesome method, didn't know it existed! Maybe there are "better" solutions nowadays, but it works and that's what I needed :)

Comment: Does anyone know if it's quicker to stream a uncompressed document vs a compressed one?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the function [`gzdecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) could help you : the manual says (quote) :

> Decodes a gzip compressed string

So, you'd have to :

- download the XML data
- get it as a string
- decompress it with `gzdecode`
- work on it with `XMLReader`

That would depend on the right extension *(`zlib` I guess)* beeing installed on your server, though...

> [*Mark*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139812/mark): Expanding on Pascal's post, here is some example code that should work for you

```
$xmlfile = fopen($linkToXmlFile,'rb');
$compressedXml = fread($xmlfile, filesize($linkToXmlFile));
fclose($xmlfile);
$uncompressedXml = gzdecode($compressedXml); 

$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->xml($uncompressedXml);
```

Comment: I had just tried this very thing before I arrived here.  This does not work because, for some reason, gzdecode (and gzread) strip all the XML tags and return only the values.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Pascal's post, here is some example code that should work for you

```
$xmlfile = fopen($linkToXmlFile,'rb');
$compressedXml = fread($xmlfile, filesize($linkToXmlFile));
fclose($xmlfile);
$uncompressedXml = gzdecode($compressedXml); 

$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->xml($uncompressedXml);
```

Comment: If it was all about adding a code-example, why don't you just edit the depending post and add it?