# Open remote gzip XML file for use with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, gzip

I'm having trouble retrieving and decompressing a remote gzip XML file.

To get the file I'm using:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/xml.gzip';
$linkToXmlFile = fopen("compress.zlib://$url", "r");
```

Then I've tried:

```
try {
    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);
    ...
}
```

To no avail.

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors do you get, where does it fail exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php open gzipped xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190906/php-open-gzipped-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this ?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("compress.zlib://$url", NULL, TRUE);
```