# Download Gzip XML File in Php

Tags: php, xml, encoding, gzip

I have an xml file around 30 MB, which is distributed to client as Gzip Xml File through URL, but the problem is that as a Client, I can't save a copy of it into the client's server, as xml file.

When I try with `SimpleXMLElement`, it says that I have a problem on:

> Request must contains the Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate header

Comment: Am I correct to assume you're doing something like this: `$xml = simplexml_load_file($someUrl);`?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is?  You are downloading a zip file and expecting it to be an XML file, its not, its a zip file.  You must first unzip it before you can treat it as an XML file.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767734/open-remote-gzip-xml-file-for-use-with-simplexml First hit with google when looking for "simplexml gzip".

Comment: Guys, read it carefully, it's not a ZIP, I never said ZIP, secondly, I did google, yahoo etc..didn't find there.. this was my last place at least for time being...

Comment: @rdlowrey no, I'm trying with SimpleXMLElement and it replies : Request must contains the Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate header

Comment: @ErmanB -- *"trying with SimpleXMLElement"* ... this doesn't mean anything. I know what the problem is, but I can't help without seeing the code you're using to generate the error and/or the exact error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP open gzipped XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190906/php-open-gzipped-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell PHP directly to uncompress from that URL so that you do not need to change headers in the HTTP stream wrapper context options:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://http://site.com");
```